# How in Django filter queryset by related objects

Tags: python, django

For example I have these models:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    some fields ...
    
class Book(models.Model):
    some fields ...

class BookInSale(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
```

I want take that objects of Sale model which contains BookInSale objects with some name.

For example there is 3 objects of Sale with related BookInSale: Sale1 - BookInsale[name='Book1'], BookInSale[name='Book2']; Sale2 - BookInsale[name='Book1']; Sale3 - BookInsale[name='Book2'], BookInSale[name='Book3'].

And I want to take only that Sale objects which has BooksInSale object with name 'Book1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Sale.objects.filter(books__name="Book1")
```